# How to append the same template twice within another template - Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I am an Angular newbie. Using Angular 1.5, I have a main template with a button. 
ui-sref on the button is linked with a ui-router that loads an image (another template). My requirement is to keep appending the same image into the main template, as many times as the user clicks the button. 
The problem that I am facing is that, each click of the button over-rides the same image template and doesn't append the image. How can this issue be resolved?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body ng-app="my-app">
<div ng-controller="main-controller">
  <md-button ui-sref="imgTemplate">Add Image</md-button>
</div>
</body>
</html>

(function() {
angular.module('app.imgTemplate').run(route);

route.$inject = ['routerHelper'];

  function route(routerHelper) {
    routerHelper.configureStates(return 
    [
      {
        state: 'imgTemplate',
        config: {
          url: '/imgTemplate',
          templateUrl: 'app/imgTemplate/imgTemplate.html',
          controller: 'imgTemplateController'
        }
      }
    ];
    );
  }
})();


<div ng-controller="imgTemplateController">
    <img src="../../system_path">
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post your code sample.

Comment: Please find the code sample added.